# Laravel -time with carbon

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table where i have to validate field. If date will be 30 days to "validto" date it'll be red ( some kind of notification that only 30 days are left). In database my field valid to is "date" type. I tried to add variable using carbon but it's not working:

**Controller:**

```
$users = User::all();
        $dt = Carbon::today();
        $ends = $dt->addDays(30);
        return view ('users.index', ['users'=>$users, 'dt'=>$dt, 'ends'=>$ends]);
```

**View:**

```
<tbody>


 @foreach($users as $user)
            <th> {{$user ->name}}</th>
            <th>{{$user ->email}}</th>
            @if($user->validTo == $ends)
          <th><p style="color:red">{{$user ->validTo}}</p></th>
          @else
          <th>{{$user->validTo}}</th>
          @endif
          @endforeach
        </tbody>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a direct comparison in your view like so.

```
<tbody>
@foreach($users as $user)
    <th>{{ $user->name }}</th>
    <th>{{ $user->email }}</th>
    @if(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffInDays($user->validTo, false) == 30)
        <th><p style="color:red">{{ $user->validTo->toDateString() }}</p></th>
    @else
        <th>{{ $user->validTo->toDateString() }}</th>
    @endif
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

Also add this to your `User` model to get the Carbon instance of the date.

```
protected $dates = ['validTo'];
```

Edit : Updated to display only date based on your comments.

Comment: It's working but the output is 2017-05-31 00:00:00 and i want only date without time how to do it? In mysql this column is date not datetime

Comment: This is wrong logic since `diffInDays()` works on both sides.

Comment: @tomczas use $user->validTo->toDateString();

Comment: @Sandeesh nope. Checking valid to date is a pretty common task, and I'm sure your code will cause errors because it will also show past `validTo` dates.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin you're right, updated code to check for absolute difference.

Comment: @tomczas do you need to show red date only when there are only 30 days left until `validTo` date? Or you need to show it when 29, 28, 27 etc days left?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gt()` to check if a date is greater than another date:

```
@if ($user->validTo->subDays(30)->gt(Carbon::now())
```

If you didn't add `validTo` to the [`$dates`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) array, do that to make the code work.

Comment: Call to a member function gt() on string

Comment: @tomczas that's because you didn't add it to the `$dates` array. When you'll do that, Laravel will automatically convert `validTo` to Carbon instance like it does with `created_at` and `updated_at`.

Comment: @Sandeesh if `validTo` is the future date, then the code is correct. Next time before downvoting, make sure you're right. At least test the code.

Comment: @Sandeesh it's ok i need only clue how to pass it so both answers are good , Yours is better but all are ok

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin i'm not trying to argue, but take the test condition of the validto to date which is 30 days fromtoday and 45 days from today and check your code. `for ($i = -35; $i <= 35 ; $i++) {
        $validTo = Carbon::today()->addDays($i);
        var_dump($validTo->toDateString());
        var_dump($validTo->gt(Carbon::now()->subDays(30)));
    }`

Comment: @Sandeesh I don't know why are you trying to test here and why do use addDays() with negative numbers. tomczas, you should add `subDays()` to a `validTo`, then it'll work.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin you're not accepting the fact that your code before edit doesn't work. I'm not advocating against using `subDays`. Your old code was flawed and needed that change to work. The test was to show you that your code before edit was flawed with both past and future dates.

Comment: @Sandeesh yes, it didn't work, but because of completely another reason. And the test doesn't test anything in this case. If I would use `addDays()` it would be a completely useless solution, because it would add 30 days to a date which is like 25 days ahead. You'd get +55 days date with your solution.